# Probability distribution of two particle types system

Tags: statistical-mechanics

Suppose that particles of two different species, A and B, can be chosen with
probability $p_A$ and $p_B$, respectively.

What would be the probability (and distribution) $p(N_A;N)$ that $N_A$ out of $N$ particles are of type A?

I'm trying to apply the Binomial distribution here but am bothered by the fact that it applies for N trials (whereas here we only do 1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These sorts of problems are easiest to think about if you build up from simpler problems.

Probability that n particles are all of type A: $p_A^{n}$.

Probability that, with two particles chosen, the first is of type A, and the second of type B: $p_A p_B$.

Probability that, with two particles chosen, one is of type A, and the other of type B (any order): $2 p_A p_B$. The $2$ is there because we have to cover the different orderings - it's actually a $2!$.

Probability that, with three particles chosen, two are of type A: $\frac{3!}{2!1!} p_A^2 p_B$. The factorial in the denominator is to cover the fact that the first and second A-type particle can be swapped.

Re-thinking the factorials, since they're easy to mess up: the product of the probabilities gives us the probability of a single ordering of As and Bs. We need to count the number of orderings with $N_A$ As, and multiply that by the probability. That's $\binom N {N_A}$, or $\frac{N}{N_A!(N-N_A)!}$.

Probability that a particular configuration, with $N_A$ A-types particles, will be chosen: $p_A^{N_A}p_B^{N-N_A}$

The general formula should now be pretty clear: $\frac{N!}{N_A!(N-N_A)!}p_A^{N_A}p_B^{N-N_A}$